# Report Builder 3 Date format

Tags: reporting-services, date-formatting, reportbuilder3.0

In Report Builder 3 the dates on reports are coming through in the format MM-DD-YYYY however in the data set (source) they are in DD-MM-YYYY format (and the query designer shows them as DD-MM-YY).

I know how we can change them on the report by formatting each column and I can also set the localisation to be en-GB but is there anyway to do this by default?

i.e to make all the dates come out in DD-MM-YYYY format for all reports so users don't have to change the localisation settings for every new report.

After reading up on this it seems that they can take the settings from the client machine however my PC location is set as UK so it doesn't seem to be picking them up.

Also the Report Server is set up as UK location.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to actually be an issue with the language pack installed in IE on the Report Server.

Everything was set to a UK locale however the language option in IE wanted to download the UK language pack.

By installing it and then selecting the UK language pack in IE for the SSRS service account this resolved the issue.

Thanks for your assistance,

Nic

Comment: Thanks for the details user3060571 - do you have any links or to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand totally right, but you can use an specific user to connect on data-source, an user only for reports. This user you can specify a "region" en-GB

[image]

Comment: Hi, this doesn't resole my issue unfortunately, is there a setting anywhere that I can set report builder to use the en-GB culture?

Comment: you need to change de user's culture : [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365164(v=sql.105).aspx)